# Perforce change list size

Tags: perforce

Someone is submitting change lists that are using up a lot of disk space on our Perforce server. I want to find the size of recent change lists so I can track down where this is happening. Is there a way to do this?

p4 sizes shows the size of files in the depot but doesn't show history. I suppose I can run this periodically and see what's growing, but I would like to look back in time.

p4 describe shows what's in change lists, but doesn't show the size of the files in the change list.

p4 diskspace shows the size of depots but doesn't show history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
p4 -Ztag -F "@=%change%" changes -s submitted -m 1000 | p4 -x - -F "%fileSize% %path%" sizes -sz | sort -rn
```

That'll give you output like:

```
23245 @=3849
22499 @=4109
22438 @=3948
```

etc (`@=change` ordered by size of all revisions in that changelist).

This isn't a perfect representation of the space on disk that each changelist eats (it doesn't account for compression on the back end), but close enough that if someone is periodically submitting a bunch of huge binaries they'll be somewhere near the top of that list, so it won't take you long to find them.

Comment: This worked. I had to use a slightly different syntax  p4 -z tag -F "@=%change%" changes -s submitted -m 1000 | p4 -z tag -x - -F "%fileSize% %path%" sizes -s | sort -rn

Comment: This has to be run from a bash (or similar) shell. The Windows command line will substitute the Windows PATH variable for %path% in the second filter. PowerShell doesn't do this, but the PowerShell sort doesn't sort numerically.

Comment: Note that if you don't have the `-z` option on the `p4 sizes` command you'll get some false positives from lazy-copy integrations (which consume no disk space on the back end).  Probably not a big deal but take care when reviewing the results to filter out stuff like branch creation (which will always look like a really big change if you aren't taking into account the fact that it's a lazy copy).

Comment: I had some problems with the -z option initially. I didn't debug it later. In the end it didn't matter as the submissions causing the problems were several gigabytes. The stood out pretty clearly from the normal code changes of a few kilobytes.

Comment: @SamStafford It's not mentioned in `p4 help sizes`, but `-s` and `-z` cannot be used together and are rejected (at least with p4 2016.2). `-z` already sums sizes, making `-s` unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to eyeball changelist by changelist, you can run p4 sizes with the changelist info, for example, if you want to know the sizes of the files in changelist #99:

`p4 sizes //...@99,99`

That doesn't give you the history, but if you can narrow it down to a particular path you could do:

```
p4 sizes //path/to/suspected/troublemakers/...@50
```

for example, until you find the culprit. If it's regularly an issue, that's easily scriptable.